# How to setup multiple Google+ pages with different languages/websites which share +1s?

Tags: google-plus-one, google-plus

How can I setup multiple Google+ pages for our product for users who speak different languages and share the +1 between those pages? We have a web domain for every language our product supports.

I saw that this should be possible by looking at some companies which have different domains and Google+ pages but the same amount of + on every page.